# ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES after upgrading to Chrome version 76.0.3809.100

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

after upgrading to Chrome 76.0.3809.100 we are facing an issue where a lot of a JS files are not loaded to `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`.

Our app is developed in ASP NET MVC and AngularJS and we have like ~2000 JS files loaded in a bundling (in production, those 2000 files are bundled and minimized with another tool to only 1 file, so the problem only appears when developing).

Our bundling renders like this:

```cs
@Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/bundles/app_bundled_mvc");
```

After upgrading Chrome version, when opening the Chrome Dev Tools we see this:

HTML Result:
[HTML Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9RLU.png)
[HTML End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6uQc.png)

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlK0Z.png)

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaMuf.png)

We also have tried to load the resources in different bundles without success.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: We are facing the same issue it seems. Team will try to downgrade Chrome for now.

Comment: @DanielLidström we still didn't found a solution or fix, we will do the same, downgrading the Chrome version.

Comment: Tested also on Canary (78) with same results.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it turned out that my physical memory (at >95% utilization at the time ) was being maxed up when opening the page. 
After closing some unused programs and freeing up physical memory, the issue went away.

```
Chrome version Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

Therefore, I'd recommend closing unused programs to free up some memory for Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

The last Chrome update from August 26 (76.0.3809.132) fixes the issue.

Comment: Weird I'm running `77.0.3865.90` and get this error. We have ~2.5k js files when doing dev.